# Program stops in an infinite loop and gives me a segmentation fault

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I'm currently learning c and i wanted to create a player vs player tic tac toe game but when i execute my programm, I always get a segmentation fault. I'm using gcc as compiler. In the main function there is a while(1) loop but it gets ignored.

here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int spieler, zug; 
    int board[9]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    Pboard(board);
    spieler=0;
    while(1){
        if(spieler==0){
            board[(Pinput(spieler)-1)]='1'; //X
            spieler=1;
        } 
        else if(spieler==1){
            board[(Pinput(spieler)-1)]='2'; //O
            spieler=0;
        }
        Pboard(board);
        if(board[0]!=' ' && board[1]!=' ' && board[2]!=' ' && board[3]!=' ' && board[4]!=' ' && board[5]!=' ' && board[6]!=' ' && board[7]!=' ' && board[8]!=' '){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }

Pboard(char board[9]){
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("   |   |\n");
    printf(" ");printf("%d", board[6]);printf(" | ");printf("%d", board[7]);printf(" | ");printf("%d", board[8]);printf("\n");
    printf("   |   |\n");
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf("   |   |\n");
    printf(" ");printf("%d", board[3]);printf(" | ");printf("%d", board[4]);printf(" | ");printf("%d", board[5]);printf("\n");
    printf("   |   |\n");
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf("   |   |\n");
    printf(" ");printf("%d", board[0]);printf(" | ");printf("%d", board[1]);printf(" | ");printf("%d", board[2]);printf("\n");
    printf("   |   |\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
}
int Pinput(int spieler){
    int zug;
    if(spieler==0){
        printf("Spieler X > ");
        scanf("%d", zug);
    }
    else{
        printf("Spieler O > ");
        scanf("%d", zug);
    }
    getchar();
    return zug;
}
```

Comment: Is `Pboard` a function? Where is its return type?

Comment: What is the input? Which line segfaults? Make sure to validate `Pinput`, if you enter one outside 1-10 you might segfault on `board`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Both usages of `scanf("%d", zug)` in `Pinput()` have undefined behaviour in several ways.  It should presumably be `scanf("%d", &zug);`  (note the ampersand).   This is essentially a typo, so voting to close accordingly.

Comment: Voting To Close as typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
scanf("%d", zug);
```

Instead of passing it an `int`, you have to pass it the address of an `int` so it can write the result to that int. Supplying the wrong type leads to undefined behavior, and a segmentation fault is a common manifestation of that. Try this instead:

```
scanf("%d", &zug);
```

I recommend checking your compiler's warnings. It might tell you that the specifier is wrong, and perhaps that the variable is used uninitialized.

Comment: In fact, this kind of bug is an indicator that the compiler has been run with insufficient warnings turned on; for GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.